# Laravel 5.3 Upgrade Forgot Password Email Never Sent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Trying to figure out why ForgotPassword is not sending an email after upgrading to 5.3.  I've traced it through PasswordBroker, User, CanResetPassword, and finally to RoutesNotifications::notify where it dips into the Service Container, and apparently sends the email instance on line 21 `app(Dispatcher::class)->send([$this], $instance);`, but no email is sent... any ideas?

I'm using the MailGun driver, and using the old mail API all the ported code is still working just reset password using the new notifications API is not.

I stuck a stub in `ResetPassword::toMail`, but it never invokes this method:

```
public function toMail()
{
    Log::info('toMail');

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
        ->action('Reset Password', url('password/reset', $this->token))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found out why it doesn't invoke `ResetPassword::toMail` the `RoutesNotifications::routeNotificationFor` mail key returns `$this->email`, and we're using `$this->username`.

Reading the docs again after flipping through the code paid off since I recognized a bit more in the docs that I had already seen and now the heading caught my eye a bit more so just look at this to quickly solve this issue [Customizing The Recipient](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#customizing-the-recipient)

Comment: I was having a similar issue, this question and answer didn't necessarily resolve it, but it pointed me in the direction that eventually did. Thank you.